# How do I create a `static` array of constant size with zeroed values, but without calloc?

Tags: c, initialization, stack, allocation

I currently have some code in a function that looks like this:

```
static const int kFrameCountSample = 250;
static float * samples = (float *)calloc(kFrameCountSample, sizeof(float));
```

I like that the samples array is zeroed out exactly once with `calloc()`.

I can also write the code so `samples` is allocated on the stack.

```
static const int kFrameCountSample = 250;
static float samples[kFrameCountSample];
```

but now `samples` is not initialized to zero values. How would I also initialize it at the time it is allocated?

Comment: `samples` isn't allocated on the stack.

Comment: It is static. Its not on the stack. And if you're C compiler is remotely modern you can simply `static float samples[kFrameCountSample] = {0};`

Comment: If it's declared static, it's probably zero'd out to begin with anyway.

Comment: The static array is allocated and initialized as the program starts up, but is not reinitialized after that unless you do it explicitly.  It will not be reinitialized each time the function containing it is called (if it is in a function).

Comment: Let me be more precise. I don't actually care if it's on the stack or not. I do care that the compiler takes care of the memory management for me.

Comment: If it's declared `static` it is *definitely* zeroed out to begin with - objects with static storage duration without an explicit initializer are initialized to zero of the appropriate type.

Comment: Is this a C++ question?  It doesn't make a lot of sense to me as a C programmer.

Comment: @caf, this is tagged under C not C++.

Comment: @JacobPollack: My comment applies to C.

Comment: I was compiling a C++ file, but this is just a C question.

Comment: @caf, I have fixed this in my answer to include the clause from the C99 standard. My bad.

Comment: @MichaelBishop, not much of the code in the question is legal C.  I don't know if it's all legal C++, but at least the const and that cast are C++-idiomatic.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**For completeness (note: this is C99 NOT C++):**

It's important to note that if you define and initialize a static array of length `k` to less than `k - 1` values then the rest will be zero-filled. Hence:

```
static float samples[kFrameCountSample];
```

... is identical to:

```
static float samples[kFrameCountSample] = { 0 }; // Zero-fills.
```

... and will zero-fill `samples`. Moreover, if you do the following:

```
static float samples[kFrameCountSample] = { 1, 2, 3 }; // Zero-fills elements of position 3 ... 250.
```

... it will zero-fill the rest of the elements that are not assigned in the initialization of `samples`.

**Remark:**

- Global variables are automatically zero-filled (and do not need to be initialized if this is the intent).
- The standard for uninitialized static objects in section **6.7.8.10** of the C99 standard says:

"If an object that has automatic storage duration is not initialized explicitly, its value is indeterminate. If an object that has static storage duration is not initialized explicitly, then:

- if it has pointer type, it is initialized to a null pointer;
- if it has arithmetic type, it is initialized to (positive or unsigned) zero;
- if it is an aggregate, every member is initialized (recursively) according to these rules;
- if it is a union, the first named member is initialized (recursively) according to these rules."

Answer (score 7):

The code that you've given:

```
static const int kFrameCountSample = 250;
static float samples[kFrameCountSample];
```

is not valid C.  Objects with static storage duration can't have variably-modified type.  On the other hand, this would be valid:

```
#define kFrameCountSample 250
static float samples[kFrameCountSample];
```

This is valid either at file scope or at function scope.  In both cases the array `samples` has static storage duration, which means that it exists for the entire life of the program and is initialized only once, at program startup.  The *only* difference is that if it's in a function, the scope of the name `samples` is restricted to the block in which it's declared.  In neither case is it likely to be allocated on the stack.

The array `samples` here *is* zero-initialized - **objects with static storage duration are never uninitialized**.  If you do not provide an explicit initializer, they are initialized to zero of the appropriate type.

If you *do* want an array stored on the stack - that is, created when the function containing the declaration is entered and destroyed when that function is exited, what C calls *automatic storage duration* - then you must declare it inside a function, omit the `static` keyword and add an explicit initializer:

```
float samples[kFrameCountSample] = { 0 };
```

(In this case `kFrameCountSample` does not need to be a macro, it can be a `static const int` if you want).

A single `{ 0 }` is fine no matter what size the array is, because objects in C are never partially initialized - if you initialize any sub-object of an array or structure, the remaining sub-objects are initialized to zero of the appropriate type, just as with objects of static storage duration.

Comment: That code does indeed compile (Clang 4.2/C-version is compiler default) without the #define. I suspect because it's a const variable, the array size can be determined at compile time.

Comment: @MichaelBishop: If you add the `-pedantic` option you'll see a warning "*variable length array folded to constant array as an extension*"

Comment: @MichaelBishop: (Although you will also need to be compiling the source as C to see that warning, not C++ - this is an area where C and C++ differ).

Answer (score 1):

An array that only has some positions initialized to a value will have zeroes at the remaining positions.

```
static const int kFrameCOuntSample = 250;
static float samples[kFrameCOuntSample] = { 0 };
```

Should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You can do memset to avoid any chances of something not being initlaized to zero.

```
static float samples[kFrameCountSample];
memset(samples,0,kFrameCountSample*sizeof(float));
```

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/memset.3.html

What it does is set a to every byte in samples.  Meaning it's going to be initialized quickly to 0.

Comment: I think the problem with that is that it will reset the samples array every time the function is called and I just want to initialize it once.

Comment: Didn't see you were creating it in a called function, just thought you were creating it in general.  My bad.